# getting elements without using getElementById in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Consider two radio buttons in HTML

```
 <input type="radio" id="genderMale" name="gender" onclick="greetGender(   )">Male</input>
 <input type="radio" id="genderFemale" name="gender" onclick="greetGender( )">Female</input>
```

to evaluate in js

```
function greetGender(){

if(genderMale.checked === true){

alert("Hello Sir");

}
else{

alert("Hello Madam");
}

}
```

this executes perfectly even though

```
document.getElementById('genderMale').checked
```

is replaced by

```
 genderMale.checked
```

somebody please explain this behavior why Id is directly accessed, is that possible am I missing something

jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/ganesh_vellanki/gcLqL57c/

thanks for time

Comment: What is the problem? And what is `genderMale` inside function that is not defined.

Comment: TL;DR version: Even if you _can_ do this, you shouldn't do this.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal That is what I would like to know,even though not getting element by Id I am able to use genderMale directly from HTML file

Comment: @JLRishe yes I should'nt do this I am shocked to see the output!!